# what is a `_dispatch()` method in SimpleXMLRPCServer in python

Tags: python, simplexmlrpcserver

I was reading the documentation of the [register_instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer.register_instance) method on SimpleXMLRPCServer. It has a method signature of:

> `SimpleXMLRPCServer.register_instance(instance[, allow_dotted_names])`

and I read about the `_dispatch()` method:

> If instance contains a _dispatch() method, it is called with the requested method name and the parameters from the request. Its API is `def _dispatch(self, method, params)` (note that params does not represent a variable argument list). If it calls an underlying function to perform its task, that function is called as `func(*params)`, expanding the parameter list. The return value from `_dispatch()` is returned to the client as the result. If instance does not have a `_dispatch()` method, it is searched for an attribute matching the name of the requested method

What is this `_dispatch()` method?

Comment: Can you at least give a link to the API?

Comment: @SethMMorton I'm sorry but I don't know what api the docs are refferening too and If i knew that I wouldn't be asking the question in first place. If it would be of any help this is where i read the description - http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#simplexmlrpcserver-objects

Comment: I wasn't complaining that you didn't know or that you were asking the question.  I was complaining that you were asking about an API without giving the link so I could help you out by reading the documentation.  When asking for help, make sure you make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @SethMMorton I'm sorry if i've offended you. I didn't mean that. I'll make sure of these kind of thing in future. I'm new to this world and sometimes not able to make things clear to people over the web.

Comment: I took no offense.  No worries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the code of SimpleXMLRPCServer and found about the _dispatch method. This is the method to resolve the call to the function on server side when requested by client. This is the doc statement - "

```
        XML-RPC calls are forwarded to a registered function that
        matches the called XML-RPC method name. If no such function
        exists then the call is forwarded to the registered instance,
        if available.

        If the registered instance has a _dispatch method then that
        method will be called with the name of the XML-RPC method and
        its parameters as a tuple
        e.g. instance._dispatch('add',(2,3))

        If the registered instance does not have a _dispatch method
        then the instance will be searched to find a matching method
        and, if found, will be called.

        Methods beginning with an '_' are considered private and will
        not be called."
```